# Multiple definition of __stginit_ when building Haskell program

Tags: haskell

Hello i am trying to build a haskell program from two files;one is a module with some functions for representing json and the other is a simple main function.Following the example from the book (RWH) the ghc crashes at linking.

```
Jlib.hs
Main.hs
```

**Main:**

```
module Main where
    import Jlib 
    import System.Environment

    main::IO()
    main=print(JObject[("p0",JNumber 3),("p1",JString "asta")])
```

I use the commands:

```
ghc -c Jlib.hs
ghc -o Main Main.hs Jlib.o
```

and i get the following error:

```
$ ghc -o Main Main.hs Jlib.o
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main.exe ...
Jlib.o:fake:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__stginit_Jlib'
.\Jlib.o:fake:(.data+0x0): first defined here
Jlib.o:fake:(.data+0x60): multiple definition of `Jlib_zdfShowJValue_closure'
```

My folder looks like this:

```
Jlib.hs
Jlib.o
Jlib.hi
Main.hs
Main.o
Main.hi
```

I am asking because this is an example from the book.

**Later Edit**: added `Jlib` module

```
module Jlib(
    JValue(..),
    getString,
    getInt,
    getBool,
    getObject,
    getArray
) where

    data JValue=JString String
                |JNumber Double
                |JBool Bool
                |JNull
                |JObject [(String,JValue)]
                |JArray [JValue]
                deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

    getString::JValue->Maybe String
    getString (JString s)=Just s
    getString _=Nothing

    getInt::JValue->Maybe Int
    getInt (JNumber n)=Just (truncate n)
    getInt _= Nothing

    getBool::JValue->Maybe Bool
    getBool (JBool b)=Just b
    getBool _=Nothing

    getObject (JObject obj)=Just obj
    getObject _=Nothing

    getArray (JArray a)=Just a
    getArray _=Nothing
```

Comment: Can we see what Jlib looks like?

Comment: Sure i didn't want to pollute the initial code snippet.I added the definition to the initial post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern GHC now implicitly uses the `--make` mode when any Haskell source is mentioned.

From the [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html?highlight=#ghc-flag---make):

> `--make`
>
> In this mode, GHC will build a multi-module Haskell program automatically, figuring out dependencies for itself. If you have a
>   straightforward Haskell program, this is likely to be much easier, and
>   faster, than using **make**. Make mode is described in [Using ghc –make](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html?highlight=#make-mode).
>
> This mode is the default if there are any Haskell source files mentioned on the command line, and in this case the `--make` option can
>   be omitted.

In your case, GHC automatically adds `Jlib` for compiling and linking since you specified `Main.hs` on the command line. Since you also specified `Jlib.o`, this causes `Jlib.o` to be linked twice, resulting in many duplicate definitions.

You can simply use

```
ghc -o Main Main.hs
```

and let GHC handle the dependencies automatically, performing compiling and linking as needed.

If you want separate compilation and linking, use instead

```
ghc -c Jlib.hs
ghc -c Main.hs
ghc -o Main Main.o Jlib.o
```